# GBQ load job failed due to file not available

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

The load job failed due to GCS file not found as below:

---

creationTime: 2015-03-26 02:40:55
startTime: 2015-03-26 02:46:47
endTime: 2015-03-26 02:46:47
job_duBpwC75IL6sPSttT3_e6NLMblE : DONE
[state] => DONE
    [errorResult] => Array
        (
            [reason] => notFound
            [message] => Not found: Google Storage File gs://vindico_impressions_out/2015_03_25/22/Campaign_021107_V3Impressions21_20150325_0059789468.csv
        )

---

But checking the the file on GCS it already existed there:

163.24 KB  2015-03-26T02:19:06Z  gs://vindico_impressions_out/2015_03_25/22/Campaign_021107_V3Impressions21_20150325_0059789468.csv#1427336346623000  metageneration=1
TOTAL: 1 objects, 167159 bytes (163.24 KB)

---

Is there any warm up period or any other parameters needs to be considered before the GCS object is available for GBQ to use?

Comment: This could be a permission issue.

Comment: I have a script which picks up file from from GCS and upload to BQ. The same file worked with same script next time without any issue.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the ingestion logs, there was an internal error reading that file; if you retry, does the error go away? I've filed an internal bug and we'll investigate more on the BigQuery / Google Cloud Storage side.

Comment: We are seeing similar bug today:
`$ bq --project_id={projectName] load {tableName} gs:// ... .csv [scheme]`
resulting:
`BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'projectName:bqjob_r1f9e75274abc7851_0000014c9850face_1': Invalid path: gs:// ... .csv`

But the file exists, when checking with `$ gsutil ls`

Comment: There is an issue today with 0-byte files returning invalid path coming from GCS. We've got a fix for it, and should be deploying it this evening.